# decode query string parameter in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a query string parameter that is passed from one page to another.

The query string contains a value "plus" in it. I know that i can url encode the query string in first page and in second page i can decode it.

However on page 2, i am using..

```
 <SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="FieldName" QueryStringField="Name" />
 </SelectParameters>
```

where and how can i decode the passed query string parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code behind

```
Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString[name]);
```

Comment: man..thanks !! i always thought i had to assign a variable to the server.urldecode..it works great..i should have atleast tried it..heheh..Thanks a bunch.